# Use sscanf to extract floats with no delimiter (using expected length only)

Tags: c++, c, text-parsing

Suppose we are reading a file formatted so that each line contains two floats, the first float takes up the first 7 characters of the line, and the second float takes up the next 7 characters of the line. For example:

```c
  1.111222.222
333.333 44.444
```

Given this sample code

```c
float a, b;
sscanf("  1.111222.222", "%7f%7f", &a, &b);
printf("%f %f\n", a, b);
```

The following is output:

```c
1.111220 2.222000
```

The 7 characters do not start counting towards the first float, until the whitespace is skipped over. Is there a way to parse these floats and include the whitespace as part of the float length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with is to read the floats in as strings, `%7[^\n]` and then parse that input as a float.

```c
float a, b;
char a_buff[7 + 1];
char b_buff[7 + 1];
sscanf("  1.111222.222", "%7[^\n]%7[^\n]", a_buff, b_buff);
sscanf(a_buff, "%f", &a);
sscanf(b_buff, "%f", &b);
printf("%f %f\n", a, b);
```